# Retrive the value of sorted array in java and iterate in it

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap

So I'm new in Java and I have a method that sort a HashMap by a rand number (big to small) and i want to pass the Players from the Hash in a List and use this sorted List to iterate with an order.

This is the method that gives a sorted Hash

```
    private void triarOrdre(PlayerOffline currentPlayer, HashMap<String, Integer> playerDiceMap) {

        if (currentPlayer.getPrimeraTirada() == 0) {
            currentPlayer.setPrimeraTirada(rollDice());
            playerDiceMap.put(currentPlayer.getName(), rollValue);
            currentPlayer.setaTiratPrimeraTirada(true);
        }

        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<>(playerDiceMap.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(sortedEntries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry2) {
                return entry2.getValue().compareTo(entry1.getValue());
            }
        });

        Log.e("Sorted Player Dice Map:", "Player - Dice Value");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedEntries) {
            String playerName = entry.getKey();
            rollValue = entry.getValue();
            Log.e("Sorted Player Dice Map:",currentPlayer.getColor()+" "+ playerName + " - " + rollValue);
        }


    }
```

And this is the onClickListener where i want to iterate with the sorted list

```
        iv_dau.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PlayerOffline currentPlayer = playersIntent.get(currentPlayerIndex);

                if (!currentPlayer.isaTiratPrimeraTirada()) {
                    triarOrdre(currentPlayer, playerDiceMap); // Triar ordre
                    currentPlayerIndex = (currentPlayerIndex + 1) % playersIntent.size();
                    return; // Skip moving the piece in the current turn
                }

                movePiece(currentPlayer); // Move the piece in UI


                currentPlayerIndex = (currentPlayerIndex + 1) % playersIntent.size();
            }
        });
```

How can i do this in a "simple way"? Im getting so confused and trying no sense things.

Thanks!

I been trying a bunch of diferents ways to do it and im not seeing how

Comment: *that sort a HashMap by a rand number* How do you sort *by* a random number?

Comment: Rewrite your Question to ask for exactly what you want, with example inputs and outputs.  “a "simple way"” to do *what* exactly?

Comment: You seem to be working too hard. Learn about `NavigableMap`/`SortedMap` such as `TreeMap`, and in Java 21+, `SequencedMap` ([JEP 431](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431)).